# CSS parallax with fixed header on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, parallax

I am trying to implement a fixed header and parallax effect which seems to work in Chrome but not on Firefox.

For the parallax I tried to use the following 2 solution:

- https://www.okgrow.com/posts/css-only-parallax
- https://alligator.io/css/pure-css-parallax/

The parallax itself worked in Firefox and in Chrome when used the 1st solution, the 2nd worked only in Chrome.

I added a fixed header to my HTML like

```
<div id="site-header">
    <div>Header</div>
</div>

#site-header {
    position: fixed; /* Fixed position - sit on top of the page */
    top: 0; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 10vh;
}
```

I added the

```
margin-top: 10vh;
height: 90vh;
```

style to the `.MainContainer` class which comes from https://www.okgrow.com/posts/css-only-parallax.
The fixed header and the parallax effect works fine in Chrome but it doesn't in Firefox.

Please check it in https://codepen.io/vikhor/pen/vMmXLR.

Could you please help what goes wrong?

Comment: There seems to be more code on those websites than what you have here, and what you have here is not enough to simulate any kind of movement, let alone a parallax effect. Please update the question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment! I added a codepen sample, would that be enough? Thanks!

Comment: That's helpful, yes, though the MCVE code, per the rules, technically needs to exist *in the question itself*. The reason for that rule is so that months or years in the future, when someone else lands on this question, and clicks the CodePen link, they don't have to risk the possibility of CodePen being defunct, or you changing the code in that link, or making it private, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add margin top to `ParallaxContainer` because you have fixed that header as a result the header will not stay on that position.

```
.ParallaxContainer {
    margin-top: 10vh;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in Firefox the header still not fixed (the ParallaxContainer div will overlap it when scrolling).

Comment: Just remove the `transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);` and remove the margin-top too `margin-top: 10vh;` if you want. See the screenshot of working example from Firefox http://prntscr.com/naetk7

Comment: Thanks but my goal is to have parallax effect and fixed header.